# Is defining / using a Macro inside a function a good style/practice?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am working on an STM32 Microcontroller and in some functions I have to do a lot of bit shifting, logical operations (and, or, xor) on bits, set/clear bits and writing / reading this code is really painful.

An example: let's assume I had to turn a device on with a digital output, and I have 5 sensors to check, where each of the sensors has its own dedicated digital Input. Some of them need to be TRUE, others need to be FALSE.

A (Pseudo-)Code would eventually look like this:

Note: this code is obviously nonsense/nothing really functional, it's just for explaining the principle.

```c
#define SENSOR1 0
#define SENSOR2 1
#define SENSOR3 2
#define SENSOR4 3
#define SENSOR5 4

void DeviceOn(void) {
   uint8_t DIOPort = ReadDIOPort();
   if((DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR1)) && (!(DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR2))) && (DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR3))) {
      turnOnDevice();
   } else {
      turnOffDevice();
   }
}
```

As you see, the if-condition becomes pretty ugly and if there are more signals involved it becomes more and more unreadable.

My idea was to define macros inside the function, only used by / within that function, to make the code more readable. This would look like this.

```c
void DeviceOn(void) {
    #define __POWER_ISOK (DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR1))
    #define __SAFETY_ISOK (!(DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR2)))
    #define __LIGHT_ISON (DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR3))
    #define __COFFEEMUG_ISFULL (DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR4))
    uint8_t DIOPort = ReadDIOPort();
    if(__POWER_ISOK && __SAFETY_ISOK && __LIGHT_ISON && __COFFEEMUG_ISFULL) {
        turnOnDevice();
    } else {
        turnOffDevice();
    }
}
```

IMHO, the if-condition is much more readable as the first example.

Is this considered to be "good coding style" or is that an absolute no-go?

I want the macros to be defined within the function, because they are ***only*** used in this one function, and it makes documentation easier:

- A Reader of this code has to only scroll up to the start of the function, and does not have to search in the C-File or even the Header-File for the definition.
- The Definitions of the bits in the Digital Input Status Variable are defined globally (at the beginning of the C-File) as they are used in other functions, too.

Of course, I'd define any macros globally, that are used in multiple functions. Of course, I could also define all macros globally, but I think that it makes the code more readable, if those who are used only in one function, are defined in that function.

Technically, I don't see any issues, as the preprocessor should replace the macros in the build process, or am I wrong?

Comment: Good practice is to avoid macros if you can. Macros are not local not typesafe and more. Have a look at something like `static constexpr unsigned int __POWER_ISOK = (DIOPort & (1 << SENSOR1));` (and for other cases you should look at function templates). Only if nothing else works resort to macros

Comment: Why `#define`? Just use normal functions and an enum class.

Comment: As to what others have already said, perhaps lambdas could be an option as well?

Comment: what are lambdas? I have to google that ...

Comment: If a macro makes more readable the code it is always welcome. You have to be aware of course of problems that can result from side effects that could result using those macros in some code constructs, or even other macros. Use well descriptive names and avoid using underscores at beginning of name. Identifiers beginning with single or double underscore are reserved for system/compiler use (see C standards **`§7.1.3 Reserved identifiers`**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate solution:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void DeviceOn(void)
{
    uint8_t DIOPort = ReadDIOPort();

    bool PowerIsOK       =    DIOPort & 1 << SENSOR1;
    bool SafetyIsOK      = ! (DIOPort & 1 << SENSOR2);
    bool LightIsOn       =    DIOPort & 1 << SENSOR3;
    bool CoffeeMugIsFull =    DIOPort & 1 << SENSOR4;

    if (PowerISOK && SafetyIsOK && LightIsOn && CoffeeMugIsFull)
        turnOnDevice();
    else
        turnOffDevice();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Marcos don't have scopes, and their definition won't end at the end of the function.

Defining macros inside of functions such that they remain defined after the function is a bad practice because programmers expect definitions to end when the scope ends. You could undefine the macros at the end of the function. That is a good practice **when the macros is needed in the first place** which isn't often.

Unnecessary use of macros is a bad practice. In this case, it  is a better practice to use constant variables instead. Variables have a type system, and scope, both of which make it easier to write a correct program.

P.S. Names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the language implementation. Don't define them yourself.